# I want to get data from database and check it with an array but it isn't working

Tags: java

I want to get data from the database and check it with an array l[].
For example, I get Saturday from the database but it isn't work.

```
String l[]={"Saturday","sunday","monday","tuesday","wednsday","Thursday"};
String y[] ={"","","","","",""};


for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
  String x=l[i];

  if(x==list){ 
    y[0]=x;
    int j=1;   
    int c=++i;
    if(c<6){
        for(c=i;c<6;c++){
           y[j]=l[c];
           j++;
        }
    }
    if(c>6){
        for(c=0;c<--i;c++){
           y[j]=l[c];
           j++;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and why are you comparing string with `==` compare it with `equals()` method?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, please look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, so that you can better describe the problem and someone here can help you.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to check the result of the SQL query, or just comparing it to an array

Answer (score 0):

You can just use streams introduced in java 8.

```
String[] l = {"Saturday","sunday","monday","tuesday","wednsday","Thursday"};
boolean contains = Arrays.stream(l).anyMatch("Saturday"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```